# How to install JAVA via aptitude?

Tags: java, aptitude

One of the open source web crawlers (Heritrix) requires Java to run. I have to install this on my CENTOS via the command line (aptitude). How?

Comment: Quick note:
The standard package manager for CentOS is YUM. Aptitude is a package manager for Debian and Ubuntu Linux or more generally, DEB-based Linux distributions, in contrast to RPM-based distributions like CentOS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a [list of good HOWTOs](http://www.google.com/search?q=centos+install+java) for Java on Centos.

BTW, CentOS' package manager is called `yum`. It generally works like `aptitude`, like

`yum search $packagename

yum install $packagename

yum remove $packagename

yum check-update

yum upgrade`